# Why is SQLite schema version in .NET always 1

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I have a sqlite database. When I query the db directly via the command line, the schema_version result is 3078.

But when I do this in .NET, the result is always '1'.

Here's a snippet:

```
public static long GetInternalSchemaVersion(this SQLiteConnection con)
{
    using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = string.Format("PRAGMA schema_version;");

        DataTable results;

        using (results = new DataTable())
        {
            using (SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                da.Fill(results);

                return results.ToEnumerable().First().GetInt32("schema_version");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wring, but isnt sqllite that filebased thing? maybe your connection string is pointing to a difent file as your .NET code and therefor it doesn't see the same schema?

Comment: Additionally, SQLite will (try to) create a new database if the file does not exist. Show the connection string.

Comment: @CL. This is a database (from a file) loaded into memory. Does that 'reset' the version info?

Comment: So you are not actually accessing the same database?

Comment: @CL. well, it's the same database, but it's loaded into memory first, and then I query the schema_version.

Comment: So you are creating a new in-memory database, and copy the data from the file database into it?

Comment: @CL. I don't know how it's being created in memory, just that's it's in memory.

Comment: You don't know what your code does? And why don't you show that code?

Comment: @CL. I don't have access to that code, I'm just trying to query an in-memory database with a mismatched schema version to the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108794/discussion-between-cyrus-and-cl).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would show the connection string you're using. The most likely case is that when you're connecting via .Net, you're not connecting to the same database. The schema version is auto-incremented by SQLite on schema change, so the fact that it's returning 1 suggests this is a new database. To verify, run another query to pull back some other data you expect to be there. You'll probably find that the db is empty.